# Fire apex class with error message in flow

Tags: visual-workflow

is there a chance to fire apex class which has only error message in visual flow ? When I click the button I would like to get error message like "Please provide value on ABC field". Button has a link to fire a flow.

Comment: Whats your use-case? and is this screen flow you are working on?

Comment: No, I would like to achieve that when I click the button, error message should appear but this error message should be exist in apex class.

So the button will fire flow and flow contains the class

Comment: Can you please share your flow using screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can call an Invocable Apex method from a Screen Flow that will return something to the Flow that can then be presented as an error on a screen element.

Unless there is complex logic evaluating the error message this overkill though.